# How to control which side a margin paragraph appears on?

Tags: latex

I would like to force a `\marginpar` to appear on the "wrong" side of the page (that is, in the left margin on a single-sided document).

My problem is *not* the slipping of `\marginpars` across pages addressed by [marginparhack](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mparhack/), but rather a desired to override the usual behavior at need. Nor does [marginnote](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=marginnote) seem to cover my needs.

What package or cantrip can I use to easily force `\marginpar`s to the side of my choosing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Mica's (slightly updated) link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Footnotes_and_Margin_Notes#Margin_Notes) leads to `\reversemarginpar` which does the trick.

Grrr...it is not as if I didn't *try* to google this!

---

The wiki the Mica and I linked moved the footnote and marginnote material to a separate page at some point. Link updated 2013-04-04.

Comment: :D my googling skills are percise... google for "latex force margin notes to left side of page" and it's the first link.

Comment: ... and i can't spell today...

when are comments going to editable?

Answer (score 2):

From [LaTeX Wiki Book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Formatting#Margin_Notes):

To force margin notes onto the left side of a page use:

```
\marginpar[left text]{}.
```

There is more info on that web page :D

Comment: Unfortunately that sets the text for when *LaTeX* decides to use the left margin (as in a `twosided` document), but does not force the marginpar to the left in a single sided document. But your link does give `\reversemarginpar`, which I shall now try...

Comment: Just to note that the wiki now doesn't contain any references to `left text`, but that is still visible in [Revision history of "LaTeX/Paragraph Formatting"](http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting&offset=&limit=250&action=history) from 2009 (also in the probable edit by @dmckee )... also no mention of `\reversemarginpar` anymore, but that was what works for me.. Cheers!